# Relationships – How to know which one is the parent and which one is the child

Tags: channel-entries, relationships

I am designing a website for a fashion label who have collections every season, and they do multiple 'projects' for each collection. For instance artwork, videos etc. For instance Collection A may have 3 projects attached to it, and Collection B may have 2 projects.

Collections
      - title (text input)
      - url_title (text input)
      - collection-year (text input)
      - season (select dropdown)
      - images (channel images)

Projects
      - title (text input)
      - url_title (text input)
      - project-collection (relationship to collection)
      - project-images (channel images)

Relationships seem like the best way to link a project with a collection. What I'm struggling with though is creating a submenu for the projects that are grouped by collection. For instance...

```
Collection A
- Project 1A
- Project 2A
- Project 3A

Collection B
- Project 1B
- Project 2B
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on every **project** you have to choose the **collection** it points to, the collections turns being **their child entries**.

On the menu, grouping by the collections, you gonna have to look for each one parent:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="colletions"}
  {title}
  {parents field="project-collection"}
    {parents:title}
  {/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

To who is submitting the data, is quite the opposite: they can see every project as a child of the collections. This is why, from a template coding perspective, it can looks like a little confusing.

Think this way: the channel entry which has to be submitted before is always the child and the channel which has the relationship field is always the parent. As the *collection* have to be created before the *projects*, they're the **child** entries.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much, that makes so much sense now!